# Issue to creating index in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Unable to create index for large data column getting below error

syntax **`db.APP_AIR.createIndex ({Message : 1})`**

```
Btree::insert: key too large to index, failing APP_LOG_11032016.APP_AIR.$Message_1 4058 { : "Back in 2006, we at SSSSfelt compelled to provide the hundreds of millions of underbanked SSSS, who do not have the ability to make payments onl..." }
```

kindly help me how to resolve this issue..

Comment: This is [well documented](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Index-Key-Limit) *"The total size of an index entry, which can include structural overhead depending on the BSON type, must be less than 1024 bytes."*. And in your case this would make perfect sense. It actually looks by the content that you really want a ["text index"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/) instead.

Comment: Thank you it is working fine using the db.APP_AIR.createIndex ({Message :"text"})    .... kindly advice C# syntax for the same.

Comment: It's exactly the same. BSON object naming the field with the content "text".

Comment: Refer to my answer following http://stackoverflow.com/a/40422313/1647971.