# error in monogdb "errmsg" : "WiredTigerIndex::insert: key too large to index, failing

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm creating a index in mongo:

```
db.table.createIndex({"chr" : 1, "Start" : 1, "End" : 1, "Ref" : 1, "Alt" : 1})
```

It runs for some time and gives an error msg:

```
error in monogdb "errmsg" : "WiredTigerIndex::insert: key too large to index, failing
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Hi @anop.perl, can you add some details ? for instance, is the `table` collection already populated ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot create index in mongodb, "key too large to index"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27792706/cannot-create-index-in-mongodb-key-too-large-to-index)

Answer (score 11):

In MongoDB, since 2.6, the total size of an index entry must be less than 1024 bytes. [Documentation here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Index-Key-Limit)

In other terms, at least one of your documents has a large value in one of the field you are trying to index.

It's not a good idea in general to index very large values like that because it creates a big index which is less efficient compared to a smaller one and it takes more space in RAM which could be put to better use on a MongoDB node.

You could use this : `mongod --setParameter failIndexKeyTooLong=false`.

But it doesn't look like a good idea. If you have a large text to index, you should consider using the Full Text index or you could use a Hashed index.

Comment: You are welcome @anop.perl. Please validate the answer if you think your case is closed.

Comment: In MongoDB 4.2, this limitation has been removed but my initial comment still stands: the smaller the index, the better.

Comment: how to decide between hashed index and text index?

Comment: Hashed indexes are mainly for evenly distributed insert operations in a sharded clusters when there isn't a better option. Text indexes support the $text query operator for text search queries.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be caused by having both a text index and a standard index for the same field. By deleting one of them you will be able to resolve this issue.