# Mongodb find document with too large key

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to create an index and I'm getting this error:

> 2018-12-30T15:28:30.853-0800 I COMMAND  [conn580067] command db.$cmd
>   command: createIndexes { createIndexes: "node", indexes: [ {
>   background: true, sparse: true, key: { type: 1, players: 1, ct: 1,
>   image: 1, domain: 1 }, name: "browse" } ], writeConcern: {} }
>   exception: WiredTigerIndex::insert: key too large to index, failing 
>   5813 { : "card", : null, : 1390347921368.0, :
>   "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxISEBIUEhQVFhQQEBAQDxAVFA8UFBUQFBQWFxQRFBQYHCggGBolHBQUITEhJSkrLi4uFx8zODMsNygtLisBCgoKDg0NFBAQFywcHBwsLCwsLCwsLC...",
>   : null } code:17280 numYields:3312 reslen:354 locks:{ Global: {
>   acquireCount: { r: 3313, w: 3313 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w:
>   3313, W: 2 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 3313 } }, Metadata: {
>   acquireCount: { W: 1 } } } protocol:op_query 8206ms

How do I figure out which document it is so that I can delete it?

Comment: Not sure if you have seen that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43342082/error-in-monogdb-errmsg-wiredtigerindexinsert-key-too-large-to-index-fa/43349413

Comment: @felipsmartins yes I don't want to bypass it, I think the document is broken. I want to find the document so that I can delete it.

Comment: well... maybe you want to post this question on dba.stackexchange too. maybe there  [@jmikola](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/103517/jmikola) (internal at MongoDB) or someone else can help you (like happens to me on time).

Comment: @felipsmartins thank you, didn't know that existed.

Comment: This was cross-posted to [DBA StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/226047/mongodb-find-document-with-too-large-key), where the question is more relevant.