# mongo index key limit vs index name length

Tags: mongodb

My problem is that I'm getting 
`WiredTigerIndex::insert: key too large to index` when trying to create an index and after looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27792706/cannot-create-index-in-mongodb-key-too-large-to-index), there is a lot of talk about how basically my problem is that I'm trying

> to create an index on field or fields that exceeds 1024 bytes in
>   length

What I don't understand is what does is what it mean the 'field' that is taking up 1024 bytes.
Initially I thought it means the actual name of the field, but this does not make sense because the name isn't long at all and I have much longer names in the database. 
I also see that in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/) there is talk about "Index key limit" which is "The total size of an index entry,".

And there is "Index name length", which is "Fully qualified index names" but it isn't clear to me what is each one.

Bottom line, I would like to know what is it that is constructs a 'field' that makes it exceed 1024 bytes.

Thanks very much in advance

Comment: show sample database

Comment: Thank you, I think I found the problem. 
I think that the issue is that for the field I am trying to index, there are existing documents, that for that specific field I am trying to index, contain to much data, and that is what the documentation means that the "field or fields... exceeds 1024 bytes".
Makes sense?
I'll verify and the update the question.

Comment: correct, you text index