# Creating an index on a large embedded array in mongo

Tags: mongodb, aws-documentdb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

I have a document with an embedded array. The array is just a bunch of strings. I recently came across some performance issues, so I decided to create an index. But it won't allow me to because the "key is too large to index".

I'm using AWS DocumentDB.

A sample doc looks like this:

```
{
  _id: (mongoID),
  id: (uuid),
  employees: [(uuid of another user), ...]
}
```

I saw the question [Cannot create index in mongodb, "key too large to index"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27792706/cannot-create-index-in-mongodb-key-too-large-to-index) but I didn't really see how the solution applies to my question.

Comment: Can you provide a sample document and index specification.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot create index in mongodb, "key too large to index"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27792706/cannot-create-index-in-mongodb-key-too-large-to-index)

Comment: Which MongoDB version do you use? The limit should be removed in most recent version, see [Index Key Limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#indexes)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I'm using AWS DocumentDB, as I wrote in the question. Also added a sample doc.

Comment: @Valijon I saw that answer but didn't see how it applied to my specific question.

Comment: The linked question seems to be exactly the same problem as yours. Where do you see the difference?

Comment: To me it sounds like it's talking about a single text field

Comment: > To index a field that holds an array value, MongoDB creates an index key for each element in the array.

Comment: Shouldn't have mean each element in the array has to be under the limit?

Comment: Try to run this: `db.collection.aggregate([{$unwind:"$employees"},{$group:{_id:"$employees", size:{$first:{"$strLenBytes":"$employees"}}}},{$sort:{size:-1}}])`

Comment: The top entry is 36

Comment: Sorry, execute this one: `db.collection.aggregate([{$unwind:"$employees"},{$group:{_id:"$_id", size:{$sum:{"$strLenBytes":"$employees"}}}},{$sort:{size:-1}}])`

Comment: Top entry is an array of 180507 entries...which I guess means that there are 180507 entries in that array? I will check that out since that should not be the case

Comment: No. It's total bytes per characters for each items. for instance: `["a", "b"] = 2`, `["aa", "bb"] = 4`, etc... Can you share please that document to check if it has something wrong?

Comment: it's definitely the amount in the array (I checked). I have a bug in my code, but I see somebody else just posted something which directly answers my question (in a way that I did not hope)

Answer (score 1):

We just updated this functionality, you can now create an index on arrays greater than 2048 bytes and create a compound multi-key index with multiple keys in the same array.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/04/amazon-documentdb-adds-improved-multi-key-indexing-capabilities/

Answer (score 0):

> ### Array Indexing
>
> Amazon DocumentDB indexes an array as a **single entry**. Arrays larger than 2048 bytes cannot currently be indexed.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/functional-differences.html#functional-differences.array-indexing

If `employees` has more than `56 entries`, you cannot create index

Comment: Creating an index on an array larger than 2048 bytes has been added: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/04/amazon-documentdb-adds-improved-multi-key-indexing-capabilities/